# Unpack function return tuple into key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a function that returns a tuple:

```
def foo(x):
  return (x, x*100)
```

I have a list of values that I'd like to apply the function on and then turn the results into a dictionary:

```
list_of_vals = [2, 4, 6]
result = {...magic comprehension...}
print(result)
# {2: 200, 4: 400, 6: 600}
```

I've come up with two ways to do this:

```
{ k: v for k, v in map(foo, list_of_vals)}
{ k: v for k, v in (foo(val) for val in list_of_vals} # equivalently
```

or:

```
def helper_bar(vals):
  for val in vals:
    yield(foo(val))

{k: v for k, v in helper_bar(vals)}
```

However, none of these is very readable. Furthermore, if the `list_of_vals` is humongous I don't want to create extra copies. Is there any better (efficient?) way to do this assuming I have very long list of values and `foo` is an expensive function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the [`dict` initializator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) that takes an iterable of key-value **tuples**. So this would be perfect for your function that already returns a tuple:

```
>>> dict(map(foo, list_of_vals))
{2: 200, 4: 400, 6: 600}
```

In general though, having a function that returns a key-value tuple with the identical key seems somewhat rare. Most commonly, you would just have a function that returns the value. In those cases you would use a dictionary comprehension like this:

```
{ x: foo(x) for x in list_of_vals }
```

Comment: About your "in general": I'd say it's unusual that the function returns the original parameter, and in this (and only this) case would `x: foo(x)` work, but there are many other ways a function could return a key-value tuple.

Comment: @tobias_k That’s a fair point, I’ve reworded that part a bit. Although even then you rarely really see that. It’s more common to have separate `foo`s for the key and the value then, so you do `foo(x): bar(x)`.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution is what I needed. Is there, however, any way to modify the tuple beforehand? Basically, perform this `dict(map(lambda x : (bar1(x[0]), bar2(x[1])), map(foo, vals)))` for some functions `bar1` and `bar2` but in a nicer manner?

Comment: If you have different functions for both key and value, then you’re better of with a dictionary compression again. You can do it like this though: `{ bar1(k): bar2(v) for k, v in map(foo, list_of_vals) }`

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the result of `map` to `dict` directly

```
>>> list_of_vals = [2, 4, 6]
>>> dict(map(foo, list_of_vals))
{2: 200, 4: 400, 6: 600}
```